# clang-format keeps toggling comment location

Tags: c++, clang, code-formatting, clang-format

I'm running `clang-formt` on a source file, and it keeps toggling the location of a comment, never settling on a correct location.

Here is a copy of my `.clang-format` file:

```
BasedOnStyle: Microsoft
```

Version info:

```
$ clang-format --version
clang-format version 9.0.0
```

The snippet below shows the results of when I run `clang-format` with `-i` and then `--output-replacements-xml`:

```
$ clang-format -i MyFile.cpp
$ clang-format --output-replacements-xml MyFile.cpp
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<replacements xml:space='preserve' incomplete_format='false'>
<replacement offset='2702' length='7'>&#10;            </replacement>
</replacements>
$ clang-format -i MyFile.cpp
$ clang-format MyFile.cpp
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<replacements xml:space='preserve' incomplete_format='false'>
<replacement offset='2702' length='13'>&#10;      </replacement>
</replacements>
```

As you can see, the length field of the replacement offset continues to change. If I were to keep running this over and over again, you would see it alternate between the two outcomes listed above. Essentially, it's just moving the location of a particular comment back and forth.

Here is the source in question:

Formatted version 1:

```
    if (mp) // if foo bar likes to foo, the foo
    {       // but bar foo also is bar
            // too bizz bazz buzz bizz
        status = contains(mp->foobar());
```

Formatted version 2:

```
    if (mp) // if foo bar likes to foo, the foo
    {       // but bar foo also is bar
      // too bizz bazz buzz bizz
        status = contains(mp->foobar());
```

The line in question is `// too bizz bazz buzz bizz`, as it's location never "settles." Does anyone know why this comment keeps getting moved back and forth? Also, any ideas on how on how to prevent this (change to the format file, different version of the formatter, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this is a bug in `clang-format`. The only workarounds I've found involve moving the third comment line.

- If you start with the last comment line lined up with the subsequent code line:

  ```
      if (mp) // if foo bar likes to foo, the foo
      {       // but bar foo also is bar
          // too bizz bazz buzz bizz
          status = contains(mp->foobar());
  ```

  Then it doesn't move. But if the initial indentation is anything else, it toggles like you found.
- If you set `ReflowComments: false`, then the indentation of the third comment line doesn't toggle, but the indentation does take two round trips to settle. The first invocation of `clang-format` lines up the comment with the other comments. The second invocation lines it up with the subsequent code. After that it doesn't move, like the bullet above describes. Overall, very strange behavior, and I'd assume that it will get changed/fixed in a subsequent version of `clang-format`.